# Dynamic response handling in retrofit 2

Tags: android, json, retrofit2

I want to handle different JSON response in retrofit. Their are certain condition on provided json.

My 1st json is

```
{
 "status":2,
 "profileData":{
         "profile_id":"100102",
         "profile_status":"1",
         "fname":"Vijay",
         "gender":"Male",
         "age":"27",
         "height":"19"
  },
 "msg":"LoginSuccess"
}
```

this response is for successful login

My 2nd response is

```
{
  "status":0,
  "profileData":null,
  "msg":"One or More parameters are missing"
}
```

And my 3rd response is

```
{
  "status":1,
  "profileData":null,
  "msg":"Invalid UserName or Password"
}
```

How can i handle such condition in Retrofit 2.0. In retrofit 1.X this can be done by GSON Converter, but how can we do so in Retrofit 2.0.

Comment: as i mention this answer is about retrofit 1. Since retrofit 2.0 remove callback. Which type of POJO i need to create?

Comment: Why can't you use callback? http://inthecheesefactory.com/blog/retrofit-2.0/en

Answer (score 0):

You can you use this pojo.

```
//pojo for your Response
public class ResponsePojo {
    private int status;
    private String msg;
    private ProfileData profileData;

    //your getters an setters

}

//Pojo for Profile data
public class ProfileData {
    private String height;
    private String profile_id;
    private String age;
    private String profile_status;
    private String gender;
    private String fname;

    //your getters an setters
}

//your response method
public void onResponseMethod(ResponsePojo response) {
    if (response.getStatus() == 0) {
        //One or More parameters are missing
    } else if (response.getStatus() == 1) {
        //Invalid UserName or Password
    } else if (response.getStatus() == 2) {
        //read you profile, as its not null when success.
         ProfileData profile=response.getProfileData();
    }
}
```

Your response is not exactly dynamic, where you have only null values for some keys because there data is not valid for that state.